# Create a NDArray in an oct file from a double pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, octave, armadillo

Consider the problem of creating an 3-dimensional array `NDArray` in a C++ Octave function.

I've got a double pointer `double* ptr` and the dimensions `int dim[3]` from an Armadillo `cube`. I've found a promising [`NDArray` constructor](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d3/dd5/classNDArray.html#ad1732a88ea296b1807aff756ec7be84b) in Octave docs:

```
NDArray::NDArray    (   
    double *    sdata,
    octave_idx_type     slen,
    octave_idx_type *   adims,
    void *      arep 
)
```

I can not find any description of what the arguments are, but Ive made this guess: `sdata` seems to be the raw-data pointer, `slen` and `adims` seem to be the lenght and the dim vector respectively. But, what `arep` is suppose to be?

Comment: http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/df/dd0/Array_8h_source.html  , line 135. BTW those are all protected methods.

Answer (score 0):

[The source](http://fossies.org/dox/octave-3.8.2/dNDArray_8h_source.html) of dNDArray.h says

```
// For jit support only
```

so it does not seem sure to use.

From [the octave documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles.html#Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Oct_002dFiles),

> Define the dimensions of the matrix or array with a `dim_vector` which
>   has the same characteristics as the vector returned from size. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> dim_vector dv (2); dv(0) = 2; dv(1) = 3;  // 2 rows, 3 columns Matrix
> a (dv);
> ```
>
> This can be used on all matrix and **array types**.

But this constructor is deprecated. instead, use

```
NDArray a (dim_vector(dim[0], dim[1], dim[2]));
```

Then loop over (i, j, k) indices to copy the cube to the octave array

```
double* a_vec = a.fortran_vec ();
for (int i = 0; i < dim[0]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim[1]; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < dim[2]; k++) {
            *a_vec++ = armadillo_cube(i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with armadillo but Octave is column major like Fortran. Maybe the indices need to be swapped on the assignment.

Comment: Thks ederag, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, looping over the cube (it is time consuming, isn't it?). I think there should be a way to construct a NDArray out of a `double*` and corresponding dimensions.

Comment: @carandraug in general you are right. According to [armadillo doc](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube), `cube(n_rows, n_cols, n_slices)`. So It sounds fine ?

Comment: @mvillegas I understood your question, but to my knowledge there is no official mechanism for that. And the documentation is scarce even for the element by element copy. Whether it is worth optimizing depends strongly on the time needed for the remainder of your program. Anyway, I too would love to see how to pass the whole memory bunch to octave. [This thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Changeset-octave-value-const-ArrayN-lt-octave-idx-type-gt-amp-constructor-td1651124.html) might be relevant (especially the proposed changeset).

Comment: @mvillegas since @ederag says that armadillo is also column major, you can spped this up by using fortran_vec() (see my edit).  It still causes a copy but saves the computation of the `()` operator (which is the biggest slowdown). If you can find something like that on armadillo...